# For $n \ge 3$, every subgroup of $A_n$ with index $n$, is isomorphic to $A_{n-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For $n \ge 3$, every subgroup of $A_n$ with index $n$, is isomorphic to $A_{n-1}$.

Any idea to solving it?

Comment: I guess you could use the fact that for $n \geq 5$, normal subgroups of $S_n$ are $\{e\},A_n,S_n$. Prove that a subgroup of $A_n$ with index $n$ is a normal subgroup of a group isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$. Then its cardinality implies that it can only be $A_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $H \le G$ with $|G:H|=n$ and $G \cong A_n$. The action of $G$ by multiplication  on the cosets of $H$ gives a homomorphism $\phi: G \to S_n$. For $n \ge 5$ the simplicity of $G$ implies that $\phi$ is injective. So $|{\rm Im}(\phi)| = n!/2$ and hence ${\rm Im}(\phi) = A_n$. Now $\phi(H)$ is a point stabilizer in $A_n$ which is $A_{n-1}$. So the restriction of $\phi$ to $H$ gives an isomorphism $H \cong A_{n-1}$.

You need to do the cases $n=3,4$ separately.

Comment: No I meant $\phi(H)$. I see that there are two different groups $A_n$ around, so I will edit and try and clarify.

Comment: Yes,  Corrected!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the fact that $\phi(H)$ is a point stabilizer in $A_n$ and this is $A_{n-1}$?

Comment: The stabilizer of $H$ in the action of $G$ by multiplication on the cosets of $H$ is $H$.

Comment: And what about $A_{n-1}$?

Comment: What are you asking? Obviously a point stabilizer in $A_n$ is $A_{n-1}$ acting on the other $n-1$ points.

Comment: Oh, now I get it, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487032/subgroups-of-s-n-of-index-n-are-isomorphic-to-s-n-1) proves that a subgroup of $S_n$ of index $n$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $A_n$ of index $n$. Then $H \rtimes \Bbb{Z}_2$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ of index $n$. By the result cited in the above question, $J = H \rtimes \Bbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$. But $H$ is a normal subgroup of $J$, so it can only be isomorphic to $\{e\},A_{n-1}$ or $S_{n-1}$.

On the other hand, the cardinality of $H$ is $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ which is the cardinality of $A_{n-1}$. Thus the only possibility is that $H \simeq A_{n-1}$.

Comment: You have not justified your assertion that $H \rtimes {\mathbb Z}_2$ is a subgroup of $S_n$, I think it would be better to prove it directly without appealing to the result about $S_n$.